# List of functions to list of parameters

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, functional-style

I am working in a `Dataset` and I need to create a function for a `ChartStyle` option of a `BarChart` that takes a list of the items to be plotted.  I would like to lighten the plot style colour by the value of the item to be plotted. I have created a function that gets me the list of functions for each `PlotStyle`.

```
Function[{value}, Nest[Lighter, #, 3 - value]] & /@ {Yellow, Orange, Blue}
```

`value` will be an integer between 0 and 3 inclusive.  Is there some use of `Through` or `Outer` or `Inner` or something that will map a list of length to each position in this list of functions such that:

```
{f1, f2, f3}[{x1, x2, x3}] -> {f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}
```

This is in a `Dataset` query so I'm hoping for something concise that is easy to read and that is a one liner with the function list definition given above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Inner[#1[#2] &, {f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}, List]

(*  {f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}  *)

#[[1]][#[[2]]] & /@
 Transpose[{{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}}]

(*  {f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}  *)
```

Comment: ...and my standard solution, `MapThread[#1@#2 &, {{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}}]`, which is a variant of the `Inner` solution.

Comment: ... and similar to `MapThread[Apply, {{f1, f2, f3}, Transpose[{{x1, x2, x3}}]}]`.

Answer (score 10):

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
MultiMapAt[Range[3], {f1, f2, f3}][{x1, x2, x3}]
```

$\ $`{f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}`

Which is equivalent to using

```
(Composition @@ MapThread[MapAt, {{f1, f2, f3}, Range[3]}])[{x1, x2, x3}]
```

---

Or

```
MapIndexed[{f1, f2, f3}[[First@#2]]@#1 &, {x1, x2, x3}]
```

$\ $`{f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}`

---

Or

```
#1[#2] & @@@ Thread[{{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}}]
```

$\ $`{f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}`

Which is similar to

```
#1[#2] & @@@ Thread[{f1, f2, f3} -> {x1, x2, x3}]
```

and

```
Thread[{f1, f2, f3} -> {x1, x2, x3}] /. Rule -> (#1[#2] &)
```

---

Or

```
{f1, f2, f3}~Function[, #1[#2], Listable]~{x1, x2, x3}
```

$\ $`{f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}`

Comment: Thank you for introducing MultiMapAt +1 :)

Comment: Lots on interesting solutions here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = {f1, f2, f3};
x = {x1, x2, x3};

Block[{i = 0}, List @@ (f /. s_Symbol :> s[x[[i++]]])]
```

> {f1[x1], f2[x2], f3[x3]}