# Function for adding a head to an expression

Tags: functions, core-language, functional-style

The gist of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98835/4597) is to find a function that takes a list of functions and a list of arguments and wraps each argument with the corresponding function e.g. `someFunction[{f1, f2, f3}, {arg1, arg2, arg3}]` should evaluate to `{f1[arg1], f2[arg2], f3[arg3]]}`. Of the given answers I find none that is really readable and I though that  the undeservedly seldom used `Thread` might offer a better solution. What it does is that it pairs arguments from one list with arguments from a second list

```
Thread[someHead[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]]
(* {someHead[a, x], someHead[b, y], someHead[c, z]} *)
```

The snag here is `someHead` unfortunately.  I couldn't find a nice function `someHead[f, arg]` that evaluates to `f[arg]` i.e. applies `f` as a `Head` to `arg` and I started wondering why this is.

**This brings me to my question:**
Is there a function/expression similar to `Apply`, `Map`, `Composition` and friends for basic function application, i.e. wrapping an expression with a Head? Compare for instance

```
Thread[Composition[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]]
(* {a@*x, b@*y, c@*z} *)
```

This leads to a philosophical question: In functional programming language, should there be a function for applying a function?

Comment: A hack is `Thread[Inactivate[(#1@#2 &)][{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]] // Activate` by the way. For some reason `Thread[(#1@#2 &)[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]] ` does not work.

Answer (score 9):

```
MapThread[#[#2] &, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
```

or

```
SetAttributes[someHead, Listable];
someHead[f_, arg_] = f[arg];

someHead[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]
```

> {a[x], b[y], c[z]}

Comment: You might (also) want to post these as answers to the original question I referenced in my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the deprecated since M2 (but still working) function `Compose` for this:

```
Thread[Unevaluated @ Compose[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]]
```

> {a[x], b[y], c[z]}

Alternatively, you could use:

```
someFunction = Thread @* Unevaluated @* Compose;

someFunction[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]
```

> {a[x], b[y], c[z]}

Answer (score 2):

Version 11.3 introduces [`Construct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Construct.html)

> Construct[f,x] 
>   gives f[x].

Two possible answers using the new function are

```
Thread[Unevaluated@Construct[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]]
```

and

```
MapThread[Construct, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost equivalent to `MapThread` method by Coolwater:

```
Inner[#@#2 &, {f, g, h}, {x, y, z}, List]
```